# Dar estilo al background de un texto (CSS)

Tags: html, css, web, design

Estoy intentando dar el siguiente estilo a un título:

[image: Título con background desplazado]

Podría hacerlo utilizando un div independiente y ubicarlo con las propiedades top, left, bottom o right, por ejemplo. Sin embargo, esto no sería responsive, especialmente cuando el texto cambie su longitud o sea lo suficientemente largo para hacer wrap al siguiente renglón. Con la propiedad `background-color: darkblue` logro un efecto similar, pero sin el efecto de desplazamiento hacia arriba.

Gracias!

Comment: Saludos @guillethomas, agrega el código html y css para poder ver que es lo que has probado hasta ahora, las preguntas que no cuentan con un ejemplo mínimo verificable lastimosamente no son bien recibidas. ;)

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia! Soy nuevo y no quería entorpecer agregando texto que tal vez no aportaba. La próxima vez intentaré dar más detalles. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente no es tan difícil, simplemente crea un div general, dentro pon el texto dos veces con una clase cada una y dale el color que necesitas, luego sobrepones un texto sobre el otro y con height y overflow limitas el tamaño, haces lo mismo con el overlay y listo, en tu contenedor principal solo agregar el tamaño de la fuente, si utilizas valores dinámicos tendrás tu texto responsive.

```css
/* Contenedor General */
.font {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    /* Controlar el tamaño de fuente */
    font-size: 20vw;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
/* Color 1 superpuesto */
span.color-1 {
    color: #143791;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Color 2 */
span.color-2 {
    color: #434993;
}
/* Overlay */
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #36ccfe;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Text</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="font">
        <span class="color-1">Baby</span>
        <span class="color-2">Baby</span>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estaba bloqueado, dando vueltas con las mismas alternativas y no se me ocurrió algo así. De verdad te agradezco!!